# tex4ebook: file nameof image appears right next to the image in the ebook, etc

Tags: graphics, memoir, tex4ht, endnotes, tex4ebook

I am using tex4ebook to convert a memoir class document into epub. The document has several images included thru \includegraphics{}. The images are saved as .eps in the same folder as the .tex file. I also have the graphics.4ht file in the same folder. The epub is generated with following issues:

1. The file name of image appears before the image itself (see screenshot)
2. Though I have given the option [width=\textwidth], the image appears shrunk

Couple of additional issues:

A1) Though I have set title{} and author{} in the preamble, both are missing from the epub

A2) I want to include endnotes that appear as a chapter at the end of the book, preferably split into chapters, and also hyperlinked to be displayed as a popup in the reader by clicking the endnotemark in the main body. In the PDF version, I am able to get all this (including the PDF version of hyperlinked notes and notemarks) using \postnote. In the epub with tex4ebook, I am able to get the second part (popup of endnote in the ereader - see second screenshot) by using \footnote. Is there a way to get the first part also - get all the notes printed as a end of book chapter as part of backmatter?

Very much appreciate guidance on:

1. How to prevent the filename from appearing in the epub
2. How to ensure that image in epub is scaled to width of text in the reader

I am using MacTex (Tex Live Utility 1.54 and have checked that packages are up to date as of this writing). So far, checking of epub output has been on iBooks in Mac. Yet to check on an ereader.

Here is the MWE based on the original book.

Thanks so much in advance for any help in resolving these issues.

[image: File name of image appears right next to image]

[image: How the foot note appears]

```
\documentclass[demyvopaper, openany, 10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{tex4ebook} % FOR EPUB CONVERSION
\linespread{1.15}
\settocdepth{chapter}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[setpagesize=false, hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xurl} % WORP WRAP LONG URLS
\usepackage{graphicx}  % TO EMBED IMAGES
\usepackage[format=hang,]{caption}
\captionsetup{justification   = raggedright,
              singlelinecheck = false}
\captionsetup{labelfont={sc}}
\captionsetup{font={bf}}
\newcommand{\source}[1]{\caption*{\raggedright{\fontsize{7}{8}\selectfont{\normalfont{Source: {#1}}}}} } % TO ADD "Source" TO FIGURES LEFT-ALIGNED, FONT SIZE 7

\usepackage{longtable} %
\usepackage{afterpage} % START LONGTABLE AT TOP OF NEXT PAGE
\usepackage{enumitem, amssymb} % LISTS INSIDE TABLE

\newlength\mylength % CENTERED COLUMN {C {WIDTH}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\newlist{myitemize}{itemize}{1} 
\setlist[myitemize]{label={--},nosep,leftmargin=*} % CUSTOM LIST INSIDE TABLE

\newlist{todolist}{itemize}{2} % CUSTOM LIST FOR CHECKBOX
\setlist[todolist]{label=$\square$}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox} % RESPONSE BOX FOR BR-TOOL

\usepackage{etoolbox} % TO USE AtBeginEnvironment
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont} % ADJUST FONT SIZE & FAMILY IN LONG TABLES

\usepackage{lscape} % FOR LANDSCAPE ENVIRONMENT
\usepackage{rotating}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{0.15in} % SPECIFY SPACE BETWEEN TEXT AND FLOATS

\usepackage{ragged2e} %TO ALIGN TEXT IN BOXES 
\usepackage{setspace} % TO CHANGE LINE SPACING
\usepackage{framed} % FOR TEXT IN BOXES

\def\hyph{-\penalty0\hskip0pt\relax} % FORCED HYPHENATION OF WORDS

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{MWE}
\author{Author name}
\date{}

% MAIN CONTENT
\begin{document}

\chapter*{Chapter Title 01}

\lipsum{1-2}

% INSERT FIGURE 1.1 HERE 
\afterpage{
\begin{figure}[thp]
  \begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig0101}
  \end{center}
  \source{This figure was sourced from the internet\footnote{\url{https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/eps/eps.html}}}
  \caption{Petersen graph}
  \label{labfig0101}
\end{figure}
}

\lipsum{3-4}

%\backmatter

%\printpagenotes

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you get the image name in your output. I cannot reproduce that with your MWE.

The other issues can be fixed easily:

ad 2) you use small page size, so the width assigned to your image is small. You can use the following configuration file, `config.cfg` to use the natural image size instead:

```
\Preamble{xhtml} 
\Configure{Gin-dim}{} 
\Css{img { 
    max-width: 100\%; 
    height: auto; 
}} 
\makeatletter
\let\Author\@author
\makeatother
\begin{document} 
\EndPreamble
```

Compile using:

```
$ tex4ebook -c config.cfg filename.tex
```

If you want to resize it to the reader width, replace `max-width` with `width`.

ad A1) you need to use the `\maketitle` in your document for `\author` and `\title` to have any effect.

ad A2) try the `fn-in` option. It puts footnotes at the end of the current page. You can request it using:

```
$ tex4ebook -c config.cfg filename.tex "fn-in"
```

This is the result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much michal.h21. The config.cfg file and 'fn-in" work beautifully. \maketitle sets the book title but not the author's name.

Re the image file name appearing next to image: Since you are not getting the filename with the MWE, let me try generating the epub in a different computer and revert.

Comment: the 'fn-in" puts all footnotes in a chapter at the end of the chapter. Is there another option that would place all footnotes at the end of the book, after all chapters? Thanks.

Comment: @SPRIyer for the end notes, you can try the Enotez package. I've added the support for that recently.

Comment: @SPRIyer you are right, the author name is missing. It seems to be an issue between TeX4ht and Memoir. It is set correctly when I use the Book class.

Comment: @SPRIyer I've fixed the issue with author in the config file, see the updated  answer.

Comment: Thanks michal.ht21. The author appears now. I am unable to get the epub without getting filename of image alongside. Also formatting of tables was really messy. There's a long list of glitches in table formatting. So moving to another route: LaTeX --> DOCX (pandoc) and DOCX --> epub (calibre). Tried a sample and it meets my requirements with minor edits. Sad that I am not able to directly get the epub with tex4ebook.

Thanks so much for the tex4ebook and all the help on my queries, michal.ht21!

Comment: @SPRIyer I am sorry to hear that. what kind of glitches did you had with tables?